# Rolling Calendar testing

Tags: manual-testing, test-design, testcase

A 'rolling calendar' is 12 consecutive months without regard to actual calendar year. If you started in July 2009, for example, your 12 month calendar will end in June 2010. Your 6 days off cover the entire 12 months of July - June 2010. How would you create a test for a rolling calendar? What are the necessary test steps? I have tried to create some test scenarios, but please do advice if you have some input also.
test scenario- a flight attendant is on reserve for 12 months after graduation. After 12 months of graduation, the FA climbs in seniority, the FA gets better flights. The test is to ensure that the FA's schedule is rotated without interruption by the changing year.

Comment: Perhaps you could edit your question to include the scenarios you already created.

Comment: It's hard to give you any advice without knowing what you want to test.

Answer (score 1):

Generic advice: Try for the edge cases.

January 1, December 31, February 29, leap year, leap year exceptions, non-leap year, invalid date.

How about when the day is not filled in?

Can it be interrupted, restarted?

Is it possible someone changes position during the year, changing the rolling calendar?

Any pre-existing bugs known? And so on.

Have fun!

Comment: yeah thanks a lot. hadn't thought about some of those boundaries.